# Rewriting of a derivative operator

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I came across a following calculation in a textbook and can't really understand what happened. I would appreciate if anyone could clarify:

*Define a complex variable $\zeta=x+iy$, with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the differentiation operator $\nabla$ is defined by*

$\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=2\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\zeta}}$

Two questions:

1. The first equality sign is just purely a chosen definition of the symbol $\nabla$, right? (I know that $\nabla$ in most contexts means the gradient but here it seems to be a local definition)

2.How does one obtain the second equality? Where does the *bar* on top of $\zeta$ come from? And factor 2?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes it is a local definition, the second one you can get just by computing, the bar is complex conjugation. Keep in mind these are **definitions** so you don't have to necessarily justify the equalities. Since there are two of them it might be they are only taking the first as the definition, but that's not 100% clear.

Comment: @AdamHughes thank you for the comment. Could you please show how exactly to compute the second equality? That's exactly the problem, I don't know *how* to show it

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second bit, it's not too bad, write $x= {z+\overline{z}\over 2}, y= {z-\overline{z}\over 2i}$.

Then every

> $$f(x,y)=f\left({z+\overline{z}\over 2}, {z-\overline{z}\over 2i}\right).$$

Computing we see

$${d f\over d \overline{z}} = {\partial f\over\partial x}{\partial x\over\partial \overline{z}}+{\partial f\over\partial y}{\partial y\over\partial \overline{z}}$$

But then this just gives

$${d f\over d \overline{z}}= {\partial f\over\partial x}\cdot {1\over 2}+{\partial f\over\partial y}\cdot {-1\over 2i}={1\over 2}\left({\partial f\over\partial x}+i{\partial f\over\partial y}\right).$$

So the entire operator is the one listed.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is clear now